# Unable to use self signed certificate with node-ssl-root-cas

Tags: node.js, ssl, requestjs

I am trying to use self signed certificate of badssl.com through requestjs.
I used node-ssl-root-cas to inject certificates

Here is the code & I am getting error all the time.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var buffer = fs.readFileSync('bad.crt');

request.get({
    url: 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/',
    agentOptions:{
        ca :buffer
    }
},function responseHandle(error, response, body){
    console.log(error);
});
```

I tried modifying the root array of ssl-root-cas like this

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


var buffer = fs.readFileSync('bad.crt');
var cas = require('ssl-root-cas');
cas.push(buffer);
cas.inject();


request.get({
    url: 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/'
},function responseHandle(error, response, body){
    console.log(error);
});
```

In both the cases I am getting following error

```
{ [Error: unable to verify the first certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

Is there no way to use self signed certificates with node js?

Comment: any resolution this issue, i too stuck with the same and was referencing this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas but cannpt resolve the LEAF SIGNATURE error. I'm making a post request call to an end point with proper headers and i get this error when executing that request.

Comment: No, I do not get any resolution to this yet. I had to use rejectUnauthorized flag which basically disables all checks of certificate validity for node js.

Comment: Ok, i use the same (process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';) in my code. But it looks like definitely not a good idea.

Comment: I used the same. It's not a good idea. It's like going non SSL for self signed certificate.